# on boarding screen library for compose multiplatform

Tags: controller

I'm wondering if there's an existing library or toolkit specifically designed for Compose Multiplatform that can assist in creating onboarding screens efficiently. Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that provides pre-designed components or templates for common onboarding screen patterns, such as swipe-through tutorials or feature highlights.